# Green dot in center of photo

Tags: artifacts

When I have to take a photo with smaller aperture and zoom I always get a weird green dot in the center of the image. Please, advice what causes this artifact and a proper way to avoid or fix it.

[image]

[image]

[image]

--- Added

Camera: Sony Alpha 6000, 
Lens: E3.5-5.6/PZ 16-50 OSS 0.25m/0.82ft-0.30m/0.98ft d40.5 
This lights gives exactly same results:

1. No special setup, just room with 6 led ceiling lights and window (cloudy, no sunlight)
2. Carton box with top+left+right (diffused) + ambient light from room ceiling lights (no windows, no sunlight)

--- Added 2

I do not use any filters, only camera with kit (standard) optics and on camera flash
This photo sample is item on white A4 paper sheet. It is zoomed to occupy all space.

Comment: You would want to share some more details about camera, lens and light setup. The simple answer is: it's a reflection inside the lens which can happen when light enters the lens from outside the FOV.

Comment: ......do you have any filter on the lens?

Comment: This is almost certainly [lens flare](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lens_flare). If you aren't using a lens shade, you should be. Also try taking off any filters you might have screwed to the front of the lens.

Comment: According to the EXIF, you're using flash. If it's on camera flash and you've got a flat filter on the front of the lens...

Comment: @rackandboneman I do not use any filters, only camera with kit (standard) optics and on camera flash

Comment: Can you add a second sample image showing the dot? Can you add a photo of the rear element of the lens? I'm curious about the shape – flat, concave, convex.

Answer (score 1):

If it is always in the center it could be a reflection off the sensor. This usually happens when an older lens is used, one designed before digital. Film is less reflective than a sensor. This should not happen with a modern lens under normal conditions. The key word is *normal*, your setup may not be not normal, it may be pushing the limit.

To get detail on your black subject, you may have increased the exposure too much causing the white background to be way overexposed. The bright white in the frame can intensify the sensor reflection.

Do you need a white background? Try gray.

Try filling the frame with the object so the white is a smaller percentage of the frame.

Or, only put the white background near the object. Put a neutral color around the perimeter of the frame. Extend the white background in post.

http://thesybersite.com/minolta/sensor-reflection/

Comment: This is not the case (old lens) as this is kit lens of A6000 Sony camera.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. The linked site depicts the same effect quite clearly. Never saw anything like this.